# why WinError 10053 occur optionally?

Tags: python, sockets

I'm creating a program that activates the timer after receiving the time, ID, and password through the socket.
and when i input "minute" value, I have winError 10053.
I can't understand, why name and hour can be sent, not minute?

this is client code

```
declStart = input("if you want to login, enter "login" ")  # GUI 생기면 버튼으로 대체

if declStart=="login":

    while True:

        cname = str(input('enter name :'))

        if ' ' in cname:
            print('Spaces are not allowed.')
            continue

        client_sock.send(cname.encode())
        is_possible_name = client_sock.recv(1024).decode()

        if is_possible_name == 'yes':

            client_sock.send('!enter'.encode())

            goaltime_hour = int(input('goaltime(hour): '))
            client_sock.send((str(goaltime_hour)).encode())

            goaltime_min = int(input('goaltime(min): '))
            client_sock.send((str(goaltime_min)).encode())

            goaltime_sec = int(input('goaltime(sec): '))
            client_sock.send((str(goaltime_sec)).encode())

        elif is_possible_name == 'overlapped':
            print('[SYSTEM] The name already exists.')

        elif len(client_sock.recv(1024).decode()) == 0:
            print('[SYSTEM] The server has been disconnected.')
            client_sock.close()
            os._exit(1)

        while True:
            if goaltime_hour <= 0 and goaltime_min <= 0:
                print('Please enter the time')
                continue
            elif (str(type(goaltime_hour)) != "<class 'int'>") or (str(type(goaltime_min)) != "<class 'int'>"):
                print("Please enter the int")
                continue
            else: break

        pw = input("enter password")
        client_sock.send((str(pw)).encode())

        print("login completed. \n ")

        break
```

server

```
class timeuser:
    name: str=None
    goaltime_hour: int=None
    goaltime_min: int=None
    goaltime_sec: int=None
    currsecond: int=0
  

while True:
    count = count + 1
    conn, addr = server_sock.accept()

    client=timeuser()

    while True:
        username = conn.recv(1024).decode()

        if not username in member_name_list:
            conn.send('yes'.encode())
            break
        else:
            conn.send('overlapped'.encode())
    client.name = username

    clientHour = int(conn.recv(1024).decode())  # 시간수신
    client.goaltime_hour = clientHour

    clientMin = int(conn.recv(1024).decode())  # 분수신
    client.goaltime_min = clientMin

    clientsec = int(conn.recv(1024).decode())  # 초수신
    client.goaltime_sec = clientsec
```

you can see entire code here :
https://github.com/whataLIN/Pysoc_myStudyTimer

I deleted All other data transmission and reception processes except hour and name, Then it worked fine.
I want to get other data with no error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error 10053 is "Connection reset" (`WSAECONNRESET`). It means the server closed its socket.

That is probably because the client sends `!enter` and the server tries to read it as a number and crashes. If you looked at the terminal where the server was running, you would see it crash.